# Mysql trigger when on update reserved cloumn sub capacity if statements

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to set check class capacity if will be full class should be 
  confirm. When I update reserved it give error. Please help. Thank you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `control_class_capacity` 
AFTER UPDATE ON  `learningcenter_class`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF NEW.capacity - NEW.reserved = 0 THEN BEGIN

UPDATE learningcenter_class SET isconfirm = 1 WHERE class_id = NEW.class_id;

END; END IF;
END
```

Comment: Count the BEGIN and the END. Same number?

Comment: You cannot action the table which called the trigger.

Comment: @P.Salmon How I can change isconfirm value to make 1. when capacity - reserved will be 0 ?  Thanks.

Comment: @jarlh number column or what number you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your class_id is unique you could change the trigger to a before trigger and set NEW.ISCONFIRM. BTW if statements in MYSQL do not require begin and end statements.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(class_id int ,capacity int, reserved int, isconfirm int);
insert into t values (1,1,0,0) , (2,1,0,0);

drop trigger if exists `control_class_capacity`;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `control_class_capacity` 
before UPDATE ON  t
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF NEW.capacity - NEW.reserved = 0 THEN

SET new.isconfirm = 1;

END IF;
END $$

delimiter ;

update t set reserved = 1 where class_id = 1;

select * from t;

+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
| class_id | capacity | reserved | isconfirm |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
|        1 |        1 |        1 |         1 |
|        2 |        1 |        0 |         0 |
+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```